# Using Google App Engine how to upload document in google docs (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-docs-api

I want to upload document, file to google docs using Google Apps Engine (python)

any code or link will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is with files Upload, You need to read data using below line in python:

function to read file size

```
def getSize(self,fileobject):
  fileobject.seek(0,2) # move the cursor to the end of the file
  size = fileobject.tell()
  return size



f = self.request.POST.get('fname').file

media = gdata.data.MediaSource(file_handle=f.read(), content_type=gdata.docs.service.SUPPORTED_FILETYPES[ext], content_length=self.getSize(self.request.POST.get('fname').file))
```

And also need to modify the gdata python library of Google to achieve this:

client.py:

in
def upload_file

replace:

```
while not entry:
 entry = self.upload_chunk(start_byte, self.file_handle.read(self.chunk_size))
 start_byte += self.chunk_size
```

With:

```
while not entry:
  entry = self.upload_chunk(start_byte, self.file_handle)
  start_byte += self.chunk_size
```

And you can upload file directory to google doc

Answer (score 3):

See [the documentation,](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html) but you might try something like:

```
ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_path='/path/to/your/test.doc',  content_type=gdata.docs.service.SUPPORTED_FILETYPES['DOC'])
entry = gd_client.Upload(ms, 'MyDocTitle')
print 'Document now accessible online at:', entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

Comment: Hi,
I have already gone from this. I am using a web form to upload my file in Google app engine now i want to store that file in google docs

I am finding solution to that problem